# XMLHttpRequest to upload a file with parameters

Tags: javascript

I want to upload a file using XMLHTTRequest for Safari 5.1 and pass parameters in the POST request.How can this be achieved?It should be in plain javascript without using any API and I am doing this as Safari does not support FileReader in 5.1 version.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', $files[i]);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){alert("Done!");}, false);
xhr.open("POST", url.getUrl('myurl'));
xhr.send(fd);
```

Is the above piece of code correct?How do I pass parameters to the POST request.

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: Where do you want to get your file from?

Comment: simple example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good.
If you want to pass additional parameters to the POST you will have to add them to the FormData.

```
var fd = new FormData();
// here the POST parameters
fd.append('parameter1', 'XXXX' );
fd.append('parameter2', 'YYYY' );
// The rest of your code
fd.append('file', $files[i]);
...
```

EDIT: I am not sure however if this functionality is supported in Safari 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try `if( window.FormData === undefined ) or if( window.FormData !== undefined )`.

for more reference [click here](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/7/30/html5-powered-ajax-file-uploads)

You should also try this one!

```
<script>
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

   function upload() 
   {
      var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");

      /* Create a FormData instance */
      var fd = new FormData();
      /* Add the file */ 
      fd.append("upload", file.files[0]);

      client.open("post",url.getUrl('myurl'), true);
      client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
      client.send(formData);  /* Send to server */ 
   }

   /* Check the response status */  
   client.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
      if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) 
      {
         alert(client.statusText);
      }
   }
</script>
```

As FormData, the ability to send() one, and the upload property (and its onprogress event) are all part of XMLHttpRequest level 2, you can test for .upload to see if you've got a level 2. I don't have a Mac handy, but the function (sadly, but correctly) returns false for Opera 11.50 (and true for Firefox 4).